# Download python-requirements.txt contents with dependencies for another platform

Tags: package-management, python

I have a python-requirements.txt file. I need its contents in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 offline system with all dependencies. I'd like to download them in another system (android).
How can I manage it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By username, but not the same problem.

Comment: Question was the relation to another question :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using android's termux:

pip download -r reqs.txt  --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --binaries-only=:all:

Not sure about the last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

On systems with `pip` you can download packages using `pip download -r requirements.txt` but this probably isn't an option on Android, so you'll need to go to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/), go through all projects from you requirements.txt file, download the packages and install the manually using `pip install package.whl`. You'll need to install `python3-pip` on your Ubuntu first, but fortunately it doesn't have a lot of dependencies so you'll probably only need [python-pip-whl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pip-whl), [python3-distutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-distutils) and [python3-pip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-pip).